# HP MICROSERVER GEN8 819185-421hard drives not recognized in the front bay

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I bought that server and a SEAGATE ST1000DM003 1TB Hard drive. I've installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a SD card on the server.

It seems that the server doesn't recognise the 1TB hard drive in the front bay. I've tried switching the HD into all of the bay ports (there are 4) but it isn't recognised.

I've tried switching from BIOS from RAID to AHCI and AHCI legacy and none of those options recognise the HD.

Can someone please explain why this happens and how can I make that HD be recognised and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the 1TB drive to FAT32 or NTFS. If you can't, try using an external hard disk enclosure and plug it into another machine and format it.

If the hard drive is not detected in the BIOS, perhaps the drive may be faulty. See if it detects on another machine.

Another thing to check is if there are jumpers on the back of the hard drive.  I haven't seen jumpers on newer SATA drives but it could be there.

If using RAID card, make sure battery is not dead. Check BIOS for SATA drives  and make sure your drive is enabled.